# accessing values stored in an R confusion matrix conf_mat() by indexing

Tags: confusion-matrix

I have R code that creates a confusion matrix.  My code is along the lines of

`my_conf_mat <- data_predictions %>%  conf_mat(truth = true_labes, estimate = .pred_class)`

I get this output, which I'm satisfied with

`Truth Prediction no yes no  89 14 yes 105 78`

I think this has created a object of type conf_mat.

Now I want to store these values in variables to perform calculations.  I'm stuck on this.

If want to store the value 78 in a varaible, I have tried things like

`TP <- cheaters_conf_mat$yes[2]`

(returns NULL)

and

`TP <- cheaters_conf_mat[2,2]`

Which throws this error: "Error in cheaters_conf_mat[2, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions"

Am I close?  Any suggestions on how to store the value 78?